# Using a secrets.yml for API keys in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, key

I have a program using Stripe API. I am trying to setup a secrets.yml file that will be in the .gitignore. Here's my current attempt:

secrets.yml:

```
stripe:
 STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY: key1
 STRIPE_SECRET_KEY: key2
```

The relevant application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.include=secrets
spring.config.additional-location=classpath:secrets.yml
```

Both files are in `src/main/resource/`

This is the Java code:

```
@Value("${STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}")
private String secretKey;

@Value("${STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}")
private String stripePublicKey;
```

The program works correctly when the keys are inside application.properties.

EDIT:

When I use a non-top level yml, it still fails. secrets.yml:

```
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY: key1
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY: key2
```

Comment: Try secrets.yml without the top-level stripe: Unless there is something in your code but unshared that we should know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `spring.config.additional-location=classpath:secrets.yml`
use `spring.config.import=optional:secrets.yml`

also, remove `stripe` parent element in your secrets.yml if you want to access the values as you specified.